# Fastest way to evaluate the sum of a function over a rectangular grid

Tags: python, math, sum, vectorization

Consider a function `f(m,n)`. I want to sum this function over a rectangular grid for `m` in `range(1,M)` and `n` in `range(1,N)`. What is the most efficient way to do this? Can I get an order of magnitude (or more) speed up over what I have tried so far?

I am using `numpy.ogrid` and vectorisation.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def f(m,n):
    return 1 / np.power(m**2 + n**2, 2)

def sum(M, N):
    m, n = np.ogrid[1:M, 1:N]
    return np.sum(f(m, n))

start = timer()
sum(10000,10000)
end = timer()
print(f"Run time is {(end - start) * 1000} ms")
```

Returns: `Run time is 515.3399159999999 ms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `**2` or `np.square` instead of `np.power(...,2)` as python doesn't optimize the power of integers to simple multiplication.

the fastest way to do it is to use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) and compile this down to machine code, and add multithreading while you are at at.

```py
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def f(m, n):
    return 1 / np.square(m**2 + n**2, dtype=np.int64)

def sum(M, N):
    m, n = np.ogrid[1:M, 1:N]
    return f(m, n).sum()

from numba import njit, prange

@njit("f8(i8,i8)",error_model="numpy", fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def sum2(M, N):
    total_sum = 0.0
    for i in prange(1, M):
        for j in range(1, N):
            total_sum += 1 / (i**2 + j**2)**2
    return total_sum


start = timer()
res1 = sum(10000,10000)
end = timer()
print(f"Run time numpy is {(end - start) * 1000} ms")

start = timer()
res2 = sum2(10000,10000)
end = timer()
print(f"Run time numba is {(end - start) * 1000} ms")
assert np.isclose(res1, res2)
```

```
Run time numpy is 970.1803999999998 ms
Run time numba is 44.137399999999886 ms
```

as you can see numba can acheive the order of magnitude speedup.

for anyone going to comment that a threaded sum is not safe, numba converts this sum into a reduction so it is safe.

Comment: @KellyBundy that's because numpy is overflowing by using only `int32` instead of `int64`, i fixed that in the above snippet.

Comment: I doubt it was overflow, the results were close. Now they're still different. Apparently for you as well, otherwise why would you use `isclose`. Question about timing: I've [read](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html#how-to-measure-the-performance-of-numba) that we shouldn't report the time for a first call. Aren't you doing that?

Comment: (But if I run it a few times in a loop, I don't see stable significant differences, so maybe I'm overlooking a pre-compilation?)

Comment: @KellyBundy by specifying the argument types i am causing an eager compilation (as opposed to lazy compilation that you are referring), the error is happening in the 11th digit, and my instinct is telling me that it is happening due to the order of the elements in which the sum happens, due to floating point addition accuracy depending on the order of the sum.